# UITabBarController segue transitions

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller, modal-dialog, segue

I just had a question regarding a problem that I'm having between the different tabs in my UITabBarController in their transitions.  I have placed a UIGestureRecognizer inside of each of my tabs, and I would like to make each recognizer advance to the appropriate adjacent tab when initiated.  The recognizer operates functionally, but when the segue takes place and the next tab appears, the tab BAR disappears.  I've looked across this website as well as Apple's documentation on how to make the TabBar be forced to appear, but I've already tried things like "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO", to no avail.  Is there something that I'm missing in Storyboard? Or is this function simply not possible? I have tried both 'push' and 'modal' for the transitions, but both resulted in the proper window popping up without the TabBar anymore.

My flow of segues looks like a circle, with two swipe recognizers in each ViewController belonging to the TabBarController that point to the 'left' and 'right' ViewControllers next to it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want segues for this.  When you detect a gesture, all you should need to do is set the `selectedViewController` property of your `UITabBarController` to the proper "neighbor" controller.